# How to find process of .nfs files in directories and kill all

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make, fuser

I am trying to delete a folder named `sim_build` but I am not able because there are several `.nfs*` files in the `sim_build` (and also within the subfolders) that are busy/unclosed. I currently find the `.nfs*` files within directories manually using `fuser --kill /path_to_nfs/.nfs*`. after I delete all `.nfs*` files, I delete the folder using `rm -rf sim_build`.

As you can see this is way too cumbersome. What is the best way to automate it in a makefile?

any help appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure I see where the problem is. Just create a phony target without dependencies and use your script as its recipe. But using make for this is a bit strange. A bash script would do the same.

Comment: the makefile isn't only for this task. I actually have a makefile, doing quite different tasks. What I will do is to extend the `clean` to remove the `.nfs*` files too. the reason to automate is that I don't know where the`.nfs*` files reside. every time I run the simulation, some folders are generated with different names and `.nfs*` files.

Comment: In any event there's no mystery here.  Write the command lines that do what you want in your shell, then copy them into your makefile recipe, indent with TAB, and replace all `$` with `$$`.  Done.  if it doesn't work, post the rule you created, cut and paste the incorrect output, and describe what is wrong and what you wanted instead, then we can help.